# Is it possible to save the data from a Crystal subreport

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, subreports

I have a subreport which is on the second drill down level of my report. I have noticed that each time I drill down to that level the sub report records are retrieved from the database, which in my particular case is a lengthy process (well, around 2 minutes or so).

Is there any way for Crystal to save all the data read by a subreport so that on subsequent drill downs it does not refresh the sub report?

I don't mind if it has to refresh when the report is opened, but it's important for usability that it speed up significantly in general usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this sub-report called multiple times with the exact same parameters? Can you move the sub-report to a section that only runs once, like the report footer?

You could disable the `on demand` feature of the sub-report and enable the `Save Data with Report` feature on the main report. It'd make the first refresh a lot longer but then they could pass it around with the saved data.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's in the details section, as it is called each time with different parameters.

Comment: Oh, I see, you don't mind the first time load but after that you want the user to be able to  quickly browse the report? Updating my answer...

Comment: @dot : Yeah, that's essentially it. I'm hoping to run it as a scheduled report, so it could run all night if it had to, but people need to be able to drill down into the groupings without it taking minutes at a time to load their data.

I also seem to have made a mistake - the sub report is not at the detail level, but at the second group level, which is hidden until the first level is drilled in to. It appears that this hiding means the subreport doesn't run until it needs to be viewed, even though **on-demand** isn't checked...

Comment: @dot : OK, unhiding the sections certainly achieves the desired effect, but now I'm stuck with a report that looks awful! Do you know now of a way to hide the grouped section containing the subreport without clearing the data that's already been retrieved?

Comment: @dot : I found that if I unhide the groupings when the report runs I can then hide the groupings when it's finished and just click "Use saved data" to retain all the sub report information. This, coupled with the "Save Data on Report" means I can run my report overnight and then distribute it in the morning with all the data inside! Thanks so much for your help.